# google sheet importhtml with click show more

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula, urlfetch

I'm trying to import NHL data from https://www.espn.com/nhl/stats/player/_/view/skating/table/offensive/sort/goals/dir/desc

The problem is that I can't import the 733 rows because of a "Show more"  which make a little import of 51 rows. I'd like to import all 733 rows.

Here's the code that I put in a cell of my google sheet:

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.espn.com/nhl/stats/player/_/view/skating/table/offensive/sort/goals/dir/desc";"Table";2;)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract main informations with this script

```
function hockey() {
  var url = 'https://site.web.api.espn.com/apis/common/v3/sports/hockey/nhl/statistics/byathlete?region=us&lang=en&contentorigin=espn&isqualified=false&limit=1000&sort=offensive.goals%3Adesc&category=skaters'
  var json = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText())
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('extraction')
  sh.clearContents()

  var labels = []
  json.categories[0].labels.forEach(function (e) { labels.push(e) })
  json.categories[1].labels.forEach(function (e) { labels.push(e) })
  sh.getRange(1, 7, 1, labels.length).setValues([labels])

  var names = []
  json.categories[0].displayNames.forEach(function (e) { names.push(e) })
  json.categories[1].displayNames.forEach(function (e) { names.push(e) })
  sh.getRange(2, 7, 1, names.length).setValues([names])

  var athletes = []
  json.athletes.forEach(function (data) {
    var prov = []
    prov.push(data.athlete.firstName)
    prov.push(data.athlete.lastName)
    prov.push(data.athlete.debutYear)
    prov.push(data.athlete.age)
    prov.push(data.athlete.teamName)
    prov.push(data.athlete.teamShortName)
    data.categories[0].totals.forEach(function (t) { prov.push(t) })
    data.categories[1].totals.forEach(function (t) { prov.push(t) })
    athletes.push(prov)
  })
  sh.getRange(3, 1, athletes.length, athletes[0].length).setValues(athletes)
}
```

I got 970 players at once with all these informations

> GP    +/- TOI/G   SHFT    PROD    WINS    L   TOI G   A   PTS PPG PPA S   SPCT    GWG FW  FL  FO% SOA SOG SOPCT

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can try **importJson**, but you need to write some script.
Attack this URL which will return you all 970 players json format.
https://site.web.api.espn.com/apis/common/v3/sports/hockey/nhl/statistics/byathlete?region=us&lang=en&contentorigin=espn&isqualified=false&limit=1000&sort=offensive.goals%3Adesc&category=skaters.
I did it and it imports all players, but with a different format, maybe you need to fix something on script from tutorial.
Get data like this: [image]

I hope I was able to help you.

Comment: As IMPORTJSON isn't a built-in function please add more details about it.